# Некорректно работают функции hide, show, toggle при использовании jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

использую на страницах сайта jquery, подключив через cdn:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Проблема в том, что при использовании функции hide, show, toggle элемент пропадает или появляется не просто, а как будто сворачиваясь или разворачиваясь, что меня не устраивает. Хотелось бы, чтобы работало как fadeIn и fadeOut.

Comment: если хотите, чтобы работало как `fadeIn` то его и используйте. при вызове `hide` без параметров никакой анимации нет, в противном случае документировано следующее поведения `animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Некорректно работают функции hide, show, toggle при использовании jquery

Функции работают ровно так, как описано в документации:

> animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously

То есть анимируют ширину, высоту и прозрачность элемента. Причем если параметры в функцию не переданы, то анимации вообще никакой нет, блоки просто скрываются/показываются.

Если вам нужно скрытие элементов, используя только прозрачность, то используйте соответствующие функции, о которых сами же и упоминаете: `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`, `fadeToggle()`.

Попытки добиться такого же поведения от других функций не имеют смысла. По крайней мере этот смысл не описан в вашем вопросе. Если по каким-то причинам вы не можете использовать данные функции, то дополните свой вопрос, т.к. он не ясен в текущей формулировке.

Comment: Функции типа fade работают слишком медленно. Как сделать просто мгновенное скрытие/показ элементов через прозрачность?

Comment: @ArturHan как вы себе представляете мгновенное, и прозрачность? тут уж либо длительность 0, и нет анимаций вообще никаких, либо  задана какая-то длительность. есть два предустановленных параметра - `fast` (200ms)и `slow` (600мс), по умолчанию используется длительность 400мс. Используйте пресет, либо задайте нужную длительность в параметрах (`fadeIn( 100 );` - в два раза быстрее чем fast, к примеру. )

Comment: А как убрать анимацию из hide, чтобы элемент просто исчезал?

Comment: @ArturHan при вызове без параметров, там не должно быть никакой анимации.